# help starting on setting up facebook application development environment

Tags: php, windows, facebook, debugging

The basic question is, can i make a facbook app using localhost and when its complete then put it on a server. i will be using php.

i wanted to make a facebook app that integrates fully into facebook, pings user every day for input and display results on users requests, and if user wants he/she can publish results, now i have filled the form on facebook. its showing a php page now as sample code, now my question is how will i debug my app while development, now a regular php web site  will be debuged  using apache on localhost. how would that roll out when doing it.

```
$ curl -L http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/tarball/master | tar xvz
$ mv facebook-php-sdk-* facebook-php-sdk
$ cp facebook-php-sdk/examples/example.php index.php
```

Appreciate you help

```
<?php
// Awesome Facebook Application
//
// Name: ********
//

require_once 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow these steps:

use 000webhost.com for uploading your website
make a php page using phpform.org
put the link from webhost into canvas url of facebook

use this [Get User Id from Facebook in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948668/get-user-id-from-facebook-in-php) for connecting facebook api to you app